# Fixing audio drop outs of an HLS stream

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have an HLS stream that drops out on Android and the iOS but plays fine in a web browser (flash).

**Encoder:** Wirecast Pro 5.0.3

**Encoder Settings:** Output Format - (video) Flash, h.264 480x270 24fps, 365 kbps, keyframes every 48 (audio) AAC mono 96kbps 44.1hz

**Stream Address:** http://pablogott.videocdn.scaleengine.net/pablogott-iphone/play/ooftv1/playlist.m3u8

**Symptoms:** In iOS/Android, first the audio drops out and the video keeps playing. Then the video may drop out. Eventually this gets worse.

What I've tried: I have lowered the bit rate in my encoder and upgraded the hardware. I've done a speedtest and ping test to verify that bandwidth isn't an issue. I've also verified my encoder logs to make sure that my stream is flowing smoothly. I have also experimented with CBR vs VBR with no change in result.

My CDN is scaleengine.

Since the web browser plays back fine, it seems to be an issue that doesn't get picked up by a flash player, only the iOS player.

Comment: Can you add details about your encoder model, version and settings used? Can you show us the stream?

Comment: I updated the question to include those details.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing weird that I notice is that your Media Playlist only has the 3 latest segments referenced in it. Three is generally considered the absolute lower bound and may result in problematic playback behavior with some players. I recommend you increase the size of the Media Playlist to at least 10 segments.

My Media Playlist, I refer to the "chunklist" file, with contents such as the following:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:560
#EXTINF:10.367,
media_w958035845_560.ts
#EXTINF:10.033,
media_w958035845_561.ts
#EXTINF:10.134,
media_w958035845_562.ts
```

You will want to have at least 10 .ts files referenced in there. How you should achieve this depends on the packaging software you use - I am not familiar with Wirecast features on this point.

This is probably unrelated but I should also point out that you do not actually have keyframes every 48 frames - inspection of the segments indicates that keyframe mode seems to instead be "auto" which lets the encoder decide and results in fairly random keyframe distances (possibly the 48 is considered the max distance?). This is not likely to be the cause of the problems you are experiencing, though.

I used various tools to analyze the stream from different angles but, for example, the positioning of the keyframes can be seen by the following steps:

1. Use FFmpeg to convert a segment to MP4 and to remove audio: FFmpeg.exe -i segment.ts -an -vcodec copy -segment.mp4
2. Use mp4info from [Bento4](https://www.bento4.com/) to dump the frames list: mp4info.exe --show-layout segment.mp4

This will create a list of all frames in the segment, together with their sizes, timings and types. In the output frames with a type of "I" indicate keyframes.

Comment: Thank you for this. My CDN creates the HLS from my RTMP stream so I'll contact them. Can I ask what tool you used to analyze the stream?

Comment: @screamingdrills I have updated my answer to reflect the tools I used to analyze the frames.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, there are many issues with my setup but the one with the biggest impact was related to my firewire source.

All of my video is 24fps, but because I was ingesting it over firewire, it was actually coming as 60 interlaced frames. I deinterlaced at the source (it's a checkbox in Wirecast), and performance improved greatly.